# Are ".x" and "x." correct number notations?

Tags: notation

I know that sometimes the notation `.x` is used as a short form of `0.x`, but I've never heard about `x.` being a correct number (for instance, `3.`). I want to know if it's technically correct to use a short-hand notation with leading/ending dot instead of the full notation. For instance, can numbers `3.`, `.75` and `3.e10` be considered correct or not?

Comment: Define *official*.

Comment: any notation is correct if it is understood correctly. But the notation $3.$ seems not useful out of language programming or something related to representation of float points.

Comment: If you write in Excel "3," (Excel uses "," instead of "." for the decimal separator) it write "3" on the screen, without complaints.

Comment: The '3.' notation is used in some programming languages for floats as a shorthand for 3.0 . One could also make a point for significant figures (if your number is only precise to the units digit)

Comment: There is no concept of being "approved for official use" with math notation.  Sometimes something like `3.` can be used in programming languages to force a value to be a `float` data type, or at least to emphasize that it is a `float` as opposed to an `int` data type.

Comment: It should be noted that the $0.3$ format is preferred over $.3$ in important contexts. For example, if you want to write a note saying some patient needs $.3\ \rm mg$ of a certain medication, you don't want to risk someone not noticing the decimal point and accidentally administering ten times the correct amount. (This is especially true for handwritten notes)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, doesn't the decimal separator depend on what locale you use?

Comment: And what happens if the number is to end a sentence? e.g., "The legislature considered the bill declaring $\pi = 3.$ But then it was time for the August recess."

Answer (score 4):

Often $.3$ will be used as *shorthand* for $0.3$. I emphasize shorthand cause you really should only ever do this in handwriting that only yourself will be reading. And even then, how much harder is it to write the extra $0$?

Something like $3.$ you might see often in programming languages. Computers treat and store floating point numbers differently than integers, so something like `3.` or `3f` is used to designate a floating point number. However, again, it is better to write $3.0$, because it is clearer what you mean and not that much harder to write.

**Edit:** In response to your comment asking if it is "technically correct" or "wrong", there are lots of notational differences among the mathematical community, however, there are only two real standards: *correctness* and *clarity*. And some of the best writing often emphasizes the latter over the former. In this case, I'd say it is certainly more clear to write $3.0$

Answer (score 2):

Never mind "official use". Concentrate on clarity and write $0.3$ and $3.0$.

Comment: **I** approve it!  That makes it official.